# 403 while access an azure table

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to read and write over a newly created azure table, but I kept getting 403 errors.
I'm using the same account that I used to create the table. I also added the account to the contributors group.
I've tested multiple scopes thinking does might be the issue, such as:

- https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
- https://storage.azure.com/.default
- https://osnapdbexamsonthecloud.table.core.windows.net/.default
- https://osnapdbexamsonthecloud.table.core.windows.net/user_impersonation

but always got the same error

Here is the requeset I'm sending:

```
PUT https://osnapdbexamsonthecloud.table.core.windows.net/exams(PartitionKey='Osnap',RowKey='test')
Accept: application/json;odata=fullmetadata
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
authorization: Bearer CENSORED
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 27
content-type: application/json
Host: osnapdbexamsonthecloud.table.core.windows.net
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0
x-ms-version: 2019-02-02

{"id":"test","temp":"test"}
```

And this is the response I get with status code 403:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"AuthorizationPermissionMismatch","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:b3310a10-b002-0026-5cf5-3364d8000000\nTime:2023-01-29T15:22:15.9056626Z"}}}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the user has “Storage Table Contributor” role assigned to them?

Comment: If I go in the storage account -> access control IAM as the user I'm using, I can click on "view my access" and I see that I'm both Service Administrator and contributor (with "this resource" as scope).
Is this what you were referring to? Do you know of any other settings I'm missing?

Comment: Yes. Please try to assign `Storage Table Contributor` role as well there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I agree with *@Gaurav Mantri*, you need to assign **Storage Table Data Contributor** role to your Service Principal on that storage account.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I have one storage account in which I created a table named **`exams`** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated an **access token** via Postman with the below parameters:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
grant_type:client_credentials
scope: https://storage.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to perform the below operation, I got **same error** as you like this:

```json
PUT https://sristorage30.table.core.windows.net/exams(PartitionKey='sri',RowKey='test')
Authorization: Bearer <token>
x-ms-version: 2019-02-02

{   
    "id":"test",
    "temp":"test"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, try assigning [`Storage Table Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-contributor) role to your **service principal** that can be your user account or Azure AD application.

In my case, I assigned that role to the service principal of **`App`** type like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Storage accounts -> Your storage account -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment***

[image]

If you are performing the operation from your **user account**, assign that role to the service principal of **`User`** type  like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was assigning the user the "Contributor" group instead of the "Azure Table Data Contributor". Dumb mistake, thanks for the help